# Get value from radio button - "input[name='gender']:checked" returns null

Tags: javascript, html, null, radio-button

I'm trying to get value of radio input but it returns null for some reason. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">   
  <input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" />
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input name="gender" type="radio" value="female" />
  <label for="female">Female</label>
</form>
```

JS

```
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
const selectedGender = document.querySelector("input[name='gender']:checked");
```

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(selectedGender);
});
```

Why do I get null in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the querySelector, even before the selection event happens. You're just console logging it in the submit event.

All you need to do is, send `selectedGender` inside the eventListener.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const selectedGender = document.querySelector("input[name='gender']:checked");
  console.log(selectedGender);
});
```

Comment: You are right with selectedGender  but the eventlistener is never called.

Answer (score 1):

You did make the select before than the dom was ready.

You could do that inside the evenlistener function or at least in a ready function.

```
(function() {
const selectedGender = document.querySelector("input[name='gender']:checked");
console.log(selectedGender);
})();
```

or create a function to call it.

```
bigLogic = () => {

 //A lot of logic

 const selectedGender = document.querySelector("input[name='gender']:checked");
 console.log(selectedGender);
 //More logic
}


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  bigLogic();
});
```